# PHP 'include' file

Tags: php

I am working on a project which calls many php files via `<?php include 'filename'; ?>`

What I want to do is I want a php function or code that replaces all include occurences with the actual file, so that all my 6-7 files are converted into one single PHP file. I have to distribute it to many people, so having a single PHP file would be good in that context. Calling that php file would create a new php file with all the included files.

I want to ship my full project in a single file, just as adminer does !
Any idea how to do it ?

For example :-

```
...php-code...
<?php 
include 'dologin.php';
?>
...php code...
```

would be converted to :-

```
...php code...
function dologin();{
...(dologin.php file)...
...php code...
```

Comment: I don't understand the "question".

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question.

Comment: Hard to see what you're going for here, but you could just use `file_get_contents()` instead of `include`, and just write the contents of each file you read to a single file as you go. You'd need to be much more specific to say for certain.

Comment: Perhaps a `phar` archive would be helpful for this? Including them as you go sounds like a hassle for maintenance. Take a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/

Comment: Erm surely the easiest way is cut and paste?

Comment: @MrkFldig that would be very tedious to do since my project has many many includes !

Comment: Why don't you just use a zip-file with all the php files inside it? Then you can distribute just that file.

Comment: This is bound to fail, your proposed solution would change the scope of things and valid php files that end with php code but don't have a closing `?>` tag would render the result invalid.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Just to be clear, you _aren't_ setting variables in the files you're currently including _prior_ to writing them into a single file, right? You're just wanting to compile the PHP as-is over to one big file? I'd like to edit your question a bit to help it along, but I'd like to be certain first.

Comment: HOW is that too broad seriously this is getting ridiculous on stackoverflow. "What I want to do is I want a php function or code that replaces all include occurences with the actual file, so that all my 6-7 files are converted into one single PHP file."  - Right thats fine there are built in functions that do this as I demonstrated below.

Comment: Exactly @MrkFldig I agree with you, but what I wanted is the answer that I posted ! :) Your answer is just merging all files one by one, whereas I wanted to be merged where the include 'filename.php' is there. Do check out my answer !

Comment: My answer selects each included file and writes it out to the output file then writes the current one out, it should give you the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I exactly wanted. Please improve this php code if you can.

```
<?php 
$a = file_get_contents("sample file");
$match = "/include '.*';/";
    preg_match_all($match, $a, $matches);
    foreach($matches['0'] as $b)
    {

        $c = explode("'", $b);
        $c = $c['1'];
        $temp = file_get_contents($c);
        if(preg_match("/<?php/", $temp))
        {
        $a = str_replace($b, "?>". file_get_contents($c) . " \n ?>\n<?php \n", $a);
        }
        else
        {
        $a = str_replace($b, "?>". file_get_contents($c) . "\n<?php \n", $a);
        }
}
file_put_contents("combined.php", $a); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `include()` here, what you essentially want to do is take a bunch of files and combine them into one. There's no need to actually *parse* the files as you go, you just need to open them, read until the end, and stick what you got into another file - repeating until done.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$sources = array('file1.php', 'file2.php', 'file3.php');

$out = fopen('final.php', 'w+');
if ($out === false) 
    die('Could not open output file');

foreach($sources as $source) {
    $buff = file_get_contents($source);
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

fclose($out);
?>
```

Notes:

- I do very little error checking here. What happens if you can't open one of the source files, or the length of what you read is wildly different from what you expect?
- I do very little error checking here. What happens if `fwrite()` fails?
- I do very little error checking here. Is it safe to just keep appending as I do? Should newlines be injected after each file is written to the output file? Are you *sure* you won't end up with a missing `?>`
- I do very little error checking here. No editor is going to accidentally save an input file with a [byte-order-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning?

You'll of course need to handle doing something *with* the generated file, and unlinking it once done (though the flags sent to `fopen()` will truncate it, which is why I went with that family of functions, aside from the convenience of `file_get_contents()`). Check the manual for more info on how they work.

Honestly, though - depending on your platform, a simple shell script would probably suffice. I'm *pretty* sure this is what you're trying to do from the extra info you edited into your question.

Comment: An additional note (although you might mean that with your 3rd point...): Do the files that end with php code all have a closing `?>` tag? Not having that would also mess things up.

Comment: @jeroen I guess it's worth mentioning. I sort of presumed the files he's trying to bundle up are known working (hence the bundling), but it's a good enough point to make, as well as looking out for broken editors.

Comment: Note that leaving out the `?>` is actually valid and recommended: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Yeah, it would be better to just eliminate it from all the source files (if you can, I'm kind of envisioning a lot of mixed PHP/HTML from the nature of the question). He's got enough there to do something defensively. And if he's reading this comment, I hope he's on his way to the manual to see what those functions return and account for failure :)

Comment: I dont have the closing tag in any file

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Note I haven't had a chance to test this but get_included_files gives you everything thats included then you can just build a new file with the contents of all of them.

```
<?php

    ...All the include statements ....


    $my_includes = get_included_files ();
    $file = "everything.php"
     file_put_contents($file, "<?PHP");

    foreach($my_includes as $included){
       $file_contents = file_get_contents($included);

       file_put_contents($file, $file_contents, FILE_APPEND);


    }
    $this_file = __FILE__;
     // put the current file in and close
     file_put_contents($file, $this_file, FILE_APPEND);
     file_put_contents($file, "?>", FILE_APPEND);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that You want to integrate the included file into a function.
I never thought of this question before because it's useless, but maybe you have some "unknown" reasson behind that, so i have to answer.

Here is how:

dologin.php

```
<?php
... php code
?>
```

the function:

```
function dologin(){
global $variable1;
global $variable2;
// paste php code from the dologin.php file here
}
```

NOTE: 
change $variable1 and $variable2 to the variable that may be included from another file in your main file that you're trying to use the function in, if these variables are getting used in the function ithout doing this you'll face the variables scope problem.

That's it now you have a function instead of a PHP file.